# Stuck in a lab Task (image processing)

Tags: c

Hi everyone I am new to programming and I am first year in university cs.
my question Is that I am writing a program that screens simple images looking
for anomalies (indicated by excessive patterns of red). The program should load a
file and then print out whether or not the image contains more than a certain percentage
of intensive red pixels.

so far I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "scc110img.h"

int main()
{
  unsigned char* imageArray = LoadImage("red.bmp");
  int imageSize =GetSizeOfImage();
  int image;

  for (image = 0; image<imageSize; image++);
  printf("%d\n, imageArray[image]");
}
```

my question is how can I modify the program o that it prints out the amount of blue, green and red.
something like;

blue value is 0, green value is 0, red value is 0.

Comment: do you think you should've a semicolon after `for` statement.

Comment: You're going to have to make a better attempt than that before we finish your assignment for you.

Comment: I have formatted your code, as Raju says, take a look to the semicolon in the for statement

Answer (score 0):

You have a byte array (unsigned char) that represents the bytes of your image. Currently you are printing them out one byte at a time.

So to know how to get the individual rgb values you need to know how they were stored.

Its as easy as that, but don't expect someone here to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

This code is really incomplete. We don't know what your LoadImage() or GetSizeOfImage() function does but one thing is sure is that the way you are representing image in you C program is definitely not the way it is represented. A 'bmp' image has several parts and you should find out the correct way to represent it as a struct. Then you can traverse through it pixel by pixel.

I would suggest using a library pre-written such as 'libbmp' to make your task easy.